# replace class value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm newer to Javascript, so sorry if I'm taking the wrong approach.

I am looking to identify an element on a page by Class Name, hide it, and replace it with the text "Loading..."

Here's what I have so far, which does successfully blank the page, however, my replacement message doesn't show.

```
<style>
.loading{
display: block;
}
</style>
<script>

if (checkRequiredFields(document.forms[0]) && document.InfoForm.FUDF9.value=="Y1")
{
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("name");

for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.display = "none";}
}

</script>
<div id = "loading"></div>
<script>
var Message1 = "Loading...";
if (checkRequiredFields(document.forms[0]) && document.InfoForm.FUDF9.value=='Y1'){

document.getElementByClassName("loading").innerHTML = Message1;}
</script>
```

It is a class name that a lot of elements on the page have, I've tried going to a narrower class name but that doesn't seem to hide the smaller individual elements. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Okay, I reworked everything so it's all operating off an ID. Still confused about why it will blank the page but not show my message.

```
<style>
#loading{
display: block;
}
</style>
<div id = "loading"></div>
<script>

if (checkRequiredFields(document.forms[0]) && document.InfoForm.FUDF9.value=="Y1")
{
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("name");

for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.display = "none";}
}

var quickPledgeMessage1 = "Loading...";
if (checkRequiredFields(document.forms[0]) && document.InfoForm.FUDF9.value=='Y1'){

document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = quickPledgeMessage1;}
</script>
```

Comment: The method you seek is *getElement**s**ByClassName* (note plural), and it returns a NodeList so you'll need something like `document.getElementByClassName("loading")[0].innerHTML ...`. You will not see a refresh until the script finishes, you'll need to split it with *setTimeout* calls if you want to show something while processing occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Move your `script` to the bottom of the page... it is executing before the `<div id="loading"></div>` is available in the DOM. Or, wrap all the code inside a window.onload callback.

And `loading` is an ID, use `getElementById` or better yet use `querySelector`.

Lastly, the opening `{` and closing `}` brackets don't look like they match up.

```
<style>
.loading{
display: block;
}
</style>
<div id = "loading"></div>
<script>

if (checkRequiredFields(document.forms[0]) && document.InfoForm.FUDF9.value=="Y1")
{
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("name");

    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].style.display = "none";}
    }
}
var Message1 = "Loading...";
if (checkRequiredFields(document.forms[0]) && document.InfoForm.FUDF9.value=='Y1'){
    document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = Message1;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

loading is an ID. So you have two options.

```
<div id="loading"></div>
document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = Message1;
```

or

```
<div class="loading"></div>
document.getElementsByClassName("loading")[0].innerHTML = Message1;
```

Comment: [*getElementsByClassName*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#getelementsbyclassname) returns a live NodeList, not a single element.